# ARCore Unity: Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/TrackedPlaneManager.cs(113,5): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

Why am I getting this warning? None of my developed demo ARcore app is working.

Warning:

> Assets/GoogleARCore/SDK/Scripts/Managers/TrackedPlaneManager.cs(113,5): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected

I tried cloning from github the same file, but still got the same error.

Comment: Did you modify this file? When I look at it on GitHub, the corresponding line is a return statement in an if statement, with nothing else after it. So this warning shouldn't appear.

Comment: Nope, I did no changes in this file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same error but it is not a show stopper. AR apps still work nevertheless. It has to do with the original google SDK code.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: There a new ARCore SDK - version 2 available and the error is finally gone :)